# rails_admin with devise and single admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I'm using Rails 5, rails_admin and devise with the standard devise user model setup:

```
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end

  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```

I would like a single user to be able to access the /admin area. Without having to create a new "isAdmin" attribute in the User model, is it possible to simply tell rails_admin that user.id=1 is the only user that can access the /admin area?

Comment: I have hundreds of Users but I only need 1 with access to /admin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me. In rails_admin.rb, I removed the devise configuration and simply checked for current_user.id to equal 1.

```
  config.authorize_with do
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.id == 1
    else
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
    end
  end
```

This is simple and does not give away there is an /admin area unless you are the current signed in user and your id == 1